# How to get double value in php

Tags: php

Actually, I want to add two number and the result should be in double.

```
<?php

    $a=4.0;
    $b=4;
    echo $a+$b
    ?>
```

expected output will be 8.0 but it gives result 8. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php

Comment: Already tried....it's not working.

Comment: Use either `bc` or `gmp` functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's worked correctly and `$a+$b` is float, but because it's 8.0, showing 8. You can use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function to add fixed decimal point to numbers.

```
<?php
    $a=4.0;
    $b=4;
    echo $a+$b// Ouput: 8
    var_dump($a+$b); //Output: float(8)
    echo number_format($a+$b, 1); //echo with one decimal: 8.0
?>
```

You can test it with other numbers:

```
<?php
    $a=4.1;
    $b=4;
    echo $a+$b// Ouput: 8.1
    var_dump($a+$b); //Output: float(8.1)
    echo number_format($a+$b, 1); //echo with one decimal: 8.1
?>
```

Comment: Is any other way to bring 8.0, i mean without using number format?

Comment: gettype function returns double which answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $a=4.0;
    $b=4;
    echo sprintf("%.2f", $a+$b);
?>
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.